# Running a command after a command that used xargs and fswatch

Tags: linux, bash, xargs, fswatch

Hi I am trying to write a shell command that does:

1. watch a folder
2. when a file has changed copy that new file somewhere
3. then runs a make task

`fswatch  ./src | xargs -I {} cp {} ./otherfolder`

the first 2 things are working with the command above, but I cannot figure out how to run a command after this.

I've tried

`fswatch  ./src | xargs -I {} cp {} ./otherfolder && make`

That doesn't work because the && are conflicting with xargs I think

`fswatch  ./src | xargs -I {} cp {} ./otherfolder | make`

Here the make command is immediately called, not after the copying is done. (It's even called before fswatch triggers on a change)

Is it possible to run a command after the cp using xargs?

Comment: Apparently `fswatch` continues to run, so the pipeline is not finished.  The `&&` happens if and when the pipeline finishes.  (The pipe to `make` is obviously just bogus; there is no useful output from `cp` which would make sense as standard input to `make`.)

Comment: Another dirty hack would be: `fswatch  ./src | xargs -I {} cp -v {} ./otherfolder | xargs -I {} make`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to solve the problem would be to spawn a shell:

```
fswatch  ./src | xargs -I {} sh -c "cp '{}' ./otherfolder && make"
```

The contents of the double quotes are executed in a separate shell and will behave as you expect (first the copy, then the execution of make, assuming the copy was successful).

The single quotes around `{}` are advised to guard against problems when the filename contains spaces or other characters such as `*` which would otherwise be expanded by the shell.